# SSMS express login failed

Tags: sql-server

I'm very new to SQL Server.

I'm currently using SSMS 2005 Express and .Net Framework 4.6 and has this error when connecting to server.

[image: Error]

Can You please help me..TIA.

Comment: A casual search on the internet suggests that this could have something to do with the installed .NET versions (2.0 vs. 3.5 vs. ...). So, ignoring that this question is bordering "off topic", you should at least suggest which version of SSMS you are using. Good luck.

Comment: Hi @Christian.K, Thanks for pointing that out. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 (and its SQL Server Management Studio) requires version 2.0 of the .NET Framework installed.

A higher version of SSMS (i.e. 2008 R2) will connect to your SQL Server 2005 as well. SSMS 2008 R2 requires .NET Framework 3.5 SP1.

If installing additional .NET Framework versions is not possible you could install the latest SSMS version 17.4 and connect to your SQL Server. It is a free [download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) from Microsoft and requires .NET 4.6.1+ to run.